# Pass list to function argument?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, purrr

Big picture: I want my user defined function to iterate through a list (or vector) of arguments like a loop. (In this case the argument is a character string)

```
get_avg2 <- function(v_name) {

avg <- "_Average"      

data_1 <-  PFF_College_Defense_data %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Name) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise("{{ v_name }}_{avg}" := mean({{ v_name }}, na.rm = TRUE))

PFF_NCAA_Average_grades <- merge(PFF_NCAA_Average_grades, data_1, by = "Name")

return(PFF_NCAA_Average_grades)

}


v_names <- list("hits", "tackles", "forced_fumbles")

for (i in v_names) {

get_avg2(i)

}
#didn't work

PFF_NCAA_Average_grades <- purrr::map_df(v_names, get_avg2)

#didnt' work
```

I am trying to get averages by group from a dataframe and store it as another dataframe.  I have written a UDF to accept one argument as the variable name from the original database, then the UDF runs the calculation and merges it to the created dataframe which I pre-formatted to fit the results of the UDF. I want to pass a list to my function and have it iterate over that list like a loop.  Although I just can't conceptually seem to master this concept or the use of purrr::map which I thought would do the trick.

I know I can do this:

```
PFF_NCAA_Average_grades <- get_avg2(hits)

PFF_NCAA_Average_grades <- get_avg2(tackles)

PFF_NCAA_Average_grades <- get_avg2(forced_fumbles)
```

But that seems ugly and slow. Can someone please help me conceptually understand the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!!!

*** UPDATED WITH REPREX ******

```
library(tidyverse)

data_sample <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Dalton Campbell", "Dalton Campbell", "Dalton Campbell", "Andre Walker", "Andre Walker", "Andre Walker"),
  Defense_Grade = c(88, 86, 92, 94, 97, 95),
  Tackle_Grade = c(66, 69, 72, 74, 76, 78),
  Coverage_Grade = c(44, 43, 44, 76, 73, 78)
)

#Here I set up the dataframe which the function will bind to 
data_sample_averages <-  data_sample %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(Defense_Grade_Average = mean(Defense_Grade))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)


#Function which computes average of variable (the only argument) and merges it back to data_sample_averages
get_avg2 <- function(v_name) {
  
  avg <- "_Average"      
  
  data_1 <-  data_sample %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(Name) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise("{{ v_name }}_{avg}" := mean({{ v_name }}, na.rm = TRUE))
  
  data_sample_averages <- merge(data_sample_averages, data_1, by = "Name")
  
  return(data_sample_averages)

}

#This works - it computers the average of Tackle_Grade and binds it to data_sample_averages
data_sample_averages <- get_avg2(Tackle_Grade)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

#shows you the averages
print(data_sample_averages)
#>              Name Defense_Grade_Average Tackle_Grade__Average
#> 1    Andre Walker              95.33333                    76
#> 2 Dalton Campbell              88.66667                    69


#Neither of these work - this is where I'm stuck
variable_list <- list("Defense_Grade", "Tackle_Grade", "Coverage Grade")

data_sample_averages <- lapply(variable_list, get_avg2)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Defense_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA

#> Warning in mean.default(~"Defense_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Tackle_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Tackle_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Coverage Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not
#> numeric or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Coverage Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not
#> numeric or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

data_sample_averages <- purrr::map(variable_list, get_avg2)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Defense_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Defense_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Tackle_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Tackle_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Coverage Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not
#> numeric or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Coverage Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not
#> numeric or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
```

This feels like a really simple operation - compute the mean by group from one dataframe and bind it to another dataframe - that is not really the part I'm struggling with.  What I want is for my function to iterate through a series of arguments automatically. I want to quickly be able to build a list (or vector - I'm not set on using lists) of variables and pass it to the function as the argument so it builds a dataframe with the variables I feed it. But I'm open to the idea that I have something conceptually wrong and that I should be using a loop, purr, map, etc. or change the way my function is written?

Comment: did you tried `unlist`?

Comment: How do you mean? Where should I try it?

Comment: Your function seems to be a rather convoluted way of doing in the tidyverse what the base function `ave` does.

Comment: I've never used that function but it looks like it designed to work with factors whereas my grouping category is a character? will it work if I just convert my characters to factors and run it?

Comment: @Spence_p yes. It should work with characters directly though

Comment: Thanks! But I'm more concerned with my main question becuase at this point it's just bothering me that I can't get it to work - how do you iterate a custom function through a list of argumemts???

Comment: I can't completely understand what you are after, but I've keyed in on this sentence: "I am trying to get averages by group from a dataframe and store it as another dataframe."  Do you want `myDataFrame %>% dplyr::group_by(foo) %>% dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(.fns = mean))`?  This will get the mean for every group in a data.frame for each column.  If you post your data and your desired output explicitly, we'll be able to help without guessing!

Comment: Oh, and you iterate a custom function through a list of arguments with `lapply` or `sapply` (or other `apply` functions).  Here's an example that will run in base R.  It adds two exclamation points to every letter of the alphabet and returns as a list: `lapply(letters, function(letter) paste0(letter, "!!"))`.  Basically, every letter in "letters" is passed to the function, one at a time. Once that makes sense, you can move on to: `lapply(letters, paste0, "!!")`, which does the same thing.  Check lapply documentation.  The `plyr` package has expanded and "safer" (?) versions of these commands.

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @GeoffreyPoole Thank you so much! I'll look into that although I couldn't get it to work first time around.

Comment: @RonakShah my apologies - been awhile since I've been on here. I've updated with a reprex. Can you take another look and see if it makes more sense? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your standalone example and the function where you pass list is - In standalone example you are passing unquoted variable (`get_avg2(Tackle_Grade)`) whereas when passing a vector/list you are passing quoted variables. (`variable_list <- list("Defense_Grade", "Tackle_Grade", "Coverage Grade")`).

It is not easy to pass unquoted variables in a list so it is better we change our function that can accept quoted variables/strings. For that you need to change the function to :

```
library(dplyr)

get_avg2 <- function(v_name) {
  avg <- "_Average"      
  data_1 <-  data_sample %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(Name) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(!!paste0(v_name, avg):=mean(.data[[v_name]], na.rm = TRUE))
  data_sample_averages <- merge(data_sample_averages, data_1, by = "Name")
  
  return(data_sample_averages)
  
}
```

For a single value you call it as :

```
get_avg2("Tackle_Grade")

#             Name Defense_Grade_Average Tackle_Grade_Average
#1    Andre Walker              95.33333                   76
#2 Dalton Campbell              88.66667                   69
```

For list/vector of values you can then use `lapply` :

```
variable_list <- c("Defense_Grade", "Tackle_Grade", "Coverage_Grade")
lapply(variable_list, get_avg2)

#[[1]]
#             Name Defense_Grade_Average.x Defense_Grade_Average.y
#1    Andre Walker                95.33333                95.33333
#2 Dalton Campbell                88.66667                88.66667

#[[2]]
#             Name Defense_Grade_Average Tackle_Grade_Average
#1    Andre Walker              95.33333                   76
#2 Dalton Campbell              88.66667                   69

#[[3]]
#             Name Defense_Grade_Average Coverage_Grade_Average
#1    Andre Walker              95.33333               75.66667
#2 Dalton Campbell              88.66667               43.66667
```

---

However, ideally you'll not pass such variables one by one using `lapply`/`map` but use `across`

```
data_sample %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(across(ends_with('Grade'), mean, na.rm = TRUE))

#.   Name            Defense_Grade Tackle_Grade Coverage_Grade
#  <chr>                   <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 Andre Walker             95.3           76           75.7
#2 Dalton Campbell          88.7           69           43.7
```

But maybe you are building this function for something else.

Comment: Wow this is a very comprehensive answer. I'm definitely conceptually struggling with NSE. Thank you so much!!!!! I think the last solution using across may work but the "Grade" variables.. there's only about 6 of them and I have another 50+ columns all with unique type of names. so I ruled out using the _with style.  What is another way I could use across() to solve this?

Comment: You can pass column name with pattern or any particular regex. (`ends_with('Grade')`) or you can also pass it as column number i.e `cols <- c(2:5, 8, 12:15)`.

Comment: I'm sorry to bug you, trying to understand - so I would assign cols before this sequence and then call it where 'Grade' is right now?

Comment: Yes, so `cols` are assigned before and then use it in `across` like `data_sample %>%
  group_by(Name) %>% summarise(across(cols, mean, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Wow, works! thanks so much!! Only issue I had was that when assigning 'cols' it wanted zero indexing.  In this same example when I tried to set `cols <- c(2:4)` it told me 4th column doesnt exist. I had to do 1:3 which implies zero indexing? I thought R always did 1 indexing?

Comment: Yes, it is but in this case it doesn't count the `group_by` column.

Comment: I bought you a coffee! https://www.buymeacoffee.com/shahronak47                                   Thanks for being patient even when I didn't post the right reprex!